# EntityFramework core - Update a collection of data without selecting the entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How would you Upsert without select? the upsert would be a collection of entities received by a method which contains DTOs that may not be available in the database so you can NOT use attach range for example.
One way theoretically is to load the ExistingData partially with a select like `dbContext.People.Where(x => x exists in requested collection).Select(x => new Person { Id = x.Id, State = x.State }).ToList()` which just loads a part of the entity and not the heavy parts. But here if you update one of these returned entityItems from this collection it will not update because of the `new Person` its not tracking it and you also cannot say `dbContext.Entry<Person>(person).State = Modified` because it will throw an error and will tell you that ef core is already "Tracking" it.
So what to do.
One way would be to detach all of them from the `ChangeTracker` and then do the state change and it will do the update but not just on one field even if you say `dbContext.Entry<Person>(person).Property(x => x.State).Modified = true`. It will overwrite every fields that you haven't read from the database to their default value and it will make a mess in the database.
The other way would be to read the `ChangeTracker` entries and update them but it will also overwrite and it will consider like everything is chanaged.
So techinically I don't know how ef core can create the following SQL,

```
update People set state = 'Approved' where state != 'Approved'
```

without updating anything else. or loading the person first completely.

The reason for not loading your data is that you may want to update like `14000` records and those records are really heavy to load because they contain byte[] and have images stored on them for example.

BTW the lack of friendly documentation on EFCore is a disaster compare to Laravel. Recently it has cost us the loss of a huge amount of data.

btw, the examples like the code below will **NOT** work for us because they are updating one field which they know that it exists in database. But we are trying to upsert a collection which some of those DTOs may not be available in the database.

```
try
{
    using (var db = new dbContext())
    {
        // Create new stub with correct id and attach to context.
        var entity = new myEntity { PageID = pageid };
        db.Pages.Attach(entity);

        // Now the entity is being tracked by EF, update required properties.
        entity.Title = "new title";
        entity.Url = "new-url";
        
        // EF knows only to update the propeties specified above.
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch (DataException)
{
    // process exception
}
```

**Edit:** The used `ef core` version is `@3.1.9`

Comment: Update only works when the primary key is in the database.  Insert only works when the primary key is  not in the database.  A command has four methods 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Insert 4) Update.  SQLClient library has a CommandBuilder method that take a Select and create the other three.  SaveChanges will only work when all four methods are defined.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your comment. I know the basics. And this comment doesn't answer my question or point out anything relating to it. My SaveChanges actually worked that is why we had a disaster data loss. no records deleted they just got updated to their default values which in our case were mostly null

Comment: Why use EF at all? Why not issue direct SQL?

Comment: @mjwills I exactly though about this one after the mess was made. If I had tried to run a raw sql with ef core myself which is possible then that problem could be dodged. But I didn't know but I still want to know if this is possible with ef core fancy methods and if not the sql statement is the best option. Because I also don't want anyone else get into the same issue as I did with a lot of false solution which is out there.

Comment: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore can do that.

Comment: You can't do that with pure EF Core methods. EF Core (similar to EF6) is designed for load, modify, save flow. It requires you to load the collection from db, determine the CUD operations, apply them to change tracker, then save. Note that update is not done with `Update` method or setting the entity state to `Modified`, which are for "forced update" you are talking about, but with ...

Comment: [SetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyvalues.setvalues?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.PropertyValues.SetValues);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0) method, e.g. `context.Entry(dbEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity_with_modified_properties)`

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, so you mean if instead of `Modified = true` I've done set value to changed entity it was only updating the changed properties and not setting the whole record property to its default value. I have to try it with our query. right now I am recovering from the damage after that I will try this and will document the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic, I found the solution (You need to also take care about your unit tests).
Entityframework is actually working fine it can be just a lack of experience which I'm documenting here in case anyone else got into the same issue.

Consider that we have an entity for Person which has a profile picture saved as Blob on it which causes that if you do something like the following for let's say 20k people the query goes slow even when you've tried to have enough correct index on your table.
You want to do this query to update these entities based on a request.

```
var entityIdsToUpdate = request.PeopleDtos.Select(p => p.Id);
var people = dbContext.People.Where(x => entityIdsToUpdate.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This is fine and it works perfectly, you will get the `People` collection and then you can update them based on the given data.
In these kind of updates you normally will not need to update images even if you do, then you need to increase the `TimeOut1 property on your client but for our case we did not need to update the images.
So the above code will change to this.

```
var entityIdsToUpdate = request.PeopleDtos.Select(p => p.Id);
var people = dbContext.People
.Select(p => new Person { 
    Id = p.Id,
    Firstname = p.Firstname,
    Lastname = p.Lastname,
    //But no images to load
 })
 .Where(p => entityIdsToUpdate.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
```

But then with this approach, `EntityFramework` will lose the track of your entities.
So you need to attach it like this and I will tell you how **NOT** to attach it.

This is the correct way for a collection

```
dbContext.People.AttachRange(people); //These are the people you've already queried
```

Now **DO NOT** do this, you may want to do this because you get an error from the first one from `EntityFramework` which says the entity is already being tracked, trust it because it already is. I will explain after the code.

```
//Do not do this
foreach(var entry in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()) 
{
    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
}
//and then on updating a record you may write the following to attach it back
dbContext.Entry(Person).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

The above code will cause `EntityFramework` not to follow the changes on the entities anymore and by the last line you will tell it literally everything edited or not edited is changed and will cause you to **LOSE** your unedited properties like the "image".

**Note**: Now what can u do by mistake that even messes up the correct approach.
Well since you are not loading your whole entity, you may assume that it is still fine to assign values to the unloaded ones even if the value is not different than the one in the database. This causes entity framework to assume that something is changed and if you are setting a `ModifiedOn` on your records it will change it for no good reason.

And now about testing:
While you test, you may get something out from database and create a dto from that and pass the dto with the same `dbContext` to your `SystemUnderTest` the attach method will throw an error here which says this entity is already bein tracked because of that call in your test method. The best way would be create a new dbContext for each process and dispose them after you are done with them.

BTW in testing it may happen that with the same dbContext you update an entity and after the test you want to fetch if from the database. Please take note that this one which is returning to you is the "Cached" one by `EntityFramework` and if you have fetched it in the first place not completely like just with `Select(x => )` then you will get some fields as null or default value.
In this case you should do `DbContext.Entry(YOUR_ENTRY).Reload()`.

It is a really complete answer it may not directly be related to the question but all of the things mentioned above if you don't notice them may cause a disaster.

Comment: Your question states to update a collection without selecting the entities. In your answer you just read the entities. This solution doesn't work without selecting entities first.

Comment: No, this answer shows how to load part of the entity and do the update and the answer is for the time where batch update was not introduced yet by ef 7